# Can I find out current typing co-ordinates in a notepad relative to desktop window

Tags: delphi, winapi

Is it possible for me to find out the typing co-ordinates (relative to desktop co-ordinates) in a notepad window from a Delphi application? For example, if we look at the below picture, I am typing on a notepad window. Can I find out the screen co-ordinates, where I am typing on notepad.

**Edit**
It would be helpful if someone can suggest a generic solution. Answer no1 speaks about notepad. How about a console window? Is it possible to figure out the co-ordinates, if i am typing on a console window?

[image]

Comment: No. There's no generic solution. At least I can't think of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, if UAC would not disable it, you can implement the following sequence:

1. you have to learn the windows structure of the notepad. Using tools like `WinSpy++`, `WinSight` or `ProcFS for Total Commander` or whatever. And then you have to get the handle (`HWND`) of the actual editbox window. The topic of enumerating or finding other applications windows was discussed many times already on StackOverflow and on Google.
2. Then you have to ask the main edit window for it coordinates. See `Get{Client/Window}Rect` functions, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx Perhaps even better would be to `SendMessage` the `EM_GETRECT` custom message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997530.aspx
3. Then you have to know the position of caret: like `TMemo.SelEnd` and `TEdit.SelStart` - again best way would be to just read how they are implemented in VCL. Probably that would be rooted in `SendMessage(EM_GETSEL,...)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997530.aspx - there is a ready example to do this
4. Then you would have to ask Widows for relative coordinates of that position - relative to the Client Rect you get in above steps. See `EM_POSFROMCHAR` message http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761631.aspx and Delphi sample at http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33707

However some claims that this does not always work reliably: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/14951.aspx so as last resort you can use hard-core string parsing, as described in version 1 of this answer.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing limiting from the UAC side. The right way I'd say is to get the index of the current char by `EM_GETSEL`, then call `EM_POSFROMCHAR` and convert the resulting client char position to screen.

Comment: @TLama: Probably if you run Notepad as admin, but not your Delphi appl.

Comment: Oh, thanks, @TLama, edits page of MSDN did not talked about this message, while i remember there was something

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - that is what i am afraid of. Or if notepad is launched by some service or as some other user...

Comment: @Arioch - Don't worry, the *problem* constant (WM_USER + 38) that's referred in the link you posted is already commented out in richedit.pas, the one in messages.pas (214) is what will be used.

Comment: @TLama: UAC does not restrict window message interactions between processes, but UIPI does.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks. Well, since we don't know which Delphi version the topic starter has and future readers would have, let this notice remain.